# Which license WireMock Studio are currently using and is there any risks for enterprise usage purpose?

Tags: wiremock

WireMock Studio is not opensource and I can't find the License they used anywhere.
So is there any risks if we deployed it for enterprise usage purpose?

I have searched the WireMock Studio's license at github, google groups... And still cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WireMock Studio isn't really intended for enterprise usage and we've changed focus a bit, meaning we won't be releasing any new versions of it in the near future.

You're welcome to use it, but there will not be any updates, support or warranties of any kind.

I strongly recommend taking a look at [WireMock Cloud](https://wiremock.io), which is the enterprise grade edition of WireMock, and the current focus of the company's resources.